# Submit a document on a document library but not have it visible after that, is that possible?

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-online, permissions

Is it possible to have someone add a document to a document library and then hide it from everyones view except a certain person? Or would a different App be more useful for this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this through Permission management. Remove everyone permission after uploading it. The farm administrator will be able to see it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could also mimic this functionality with a drop-off library (part of [the Content Organizer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-the-content-organizer-to-route-documents-HA102772938.aspx) for all 2013 versions, including SharePoint Online) -- having it move all of the documents there somewhere else after they are uploaded. Then you could have whatever permissions you wanted on the destination libraries

Answer (score 3):

If you love the Powershell. Then you create a new Permission level call add-only and assign this permission level to all user who you want add items.

Give other person(who can view the items) as full control/ edit or whatever you want to give them

You can create an [add only permission level using the following PowerShell script.](http://sajiviswam.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/add-only-permission-level-in-sharepoint-2010/)

```
$spweb=Get-SPWeb -Identity "<site url>";
$spRoleDefinition = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleDefinition;
$spRoleDefinition.Name = "Submit only";
$spRoleDefinition.Description = "Can submit/add forms/files/items into library or list but cannot view/edit them.";
$spRoleDefinition.BasePermissions = "AddListItems, ViewPages, ViewFormPages, Open";
$spweb.RoleDefinitions.Add($spRoleDefinition);
$spweb.Dispose();
```